# Переадресация с адреса страницы на параметр get запроса

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Есть задача превратить адрес вида

```
http://my-site/news
```

в

```
http://my-site/?page=news
```

Как это реализовать? Т.е. как реализовать переход на страницу с передачей GET-параметра(который указывает на какую страницу перейти)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: читайте интернет в направлении _php роутинг_

Answer (score -1):

В корне вашего проекта создайте файл index.php, и в самом index.php делайте обработку GET параметров.

В php есть глобальный массив **$_GET**, из которого вы можете вытащить все get параметры которые были переданы. [Подробнее можете прочесть здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php)

Ну и далее нужные get параметры проверяйте и подтягивайте нужные страницы.
К примеру, можно вот так:

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page == "news")
{
    echo "Новости"; 
    //Можете сразу выводить html, или же делать редирект на другую страницу
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте в файл .htaccess следующие директивы:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /?page=$1
```

Подробности по ссылке https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: насколько я помню, ведущий слэш не передается